# Set of open sets notation

Tags: general-topology

While studing from Nakahara's book of Differential Geometry, I reached the part where topological spaces are introduced, and to define a topological space $\mathcal{T}$, they take it as a collection of subsets of a given set $X$, such that $\mathcal{T} = \left\{ U_i | i \in I \right\}$. This may be a stupid question, but I have not been able to figure what does the set $I$ is, to which $i$ belongs to. I have thought it to be the set of all possible subsets of $X$, or the set that contains the element indexes of the subsets of $X$, but these do not sound correct to me at all.

Comment: $I$ is just "some index set" (maybe $I$ is finite, or $I=\Bbb N$, or $I=[0,1]$ or some other way to index open sets)

Comment: Wow, this was really eating me up, and it was so simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A topology $\mathcal T$ on a set $X$ is a set of subsets of $X$ satisfying the well-known axioms for "open sets". Thus, letting $\mathfrak P(X)$ denote the powerset of $X$, we have $\mathcal T \subset \mathfrak P(X)$.

In my opininon there is no benefit to regard a topology as an *indexed collection* $\{U_i \mid  i\in I\}$. Writing it in this form means that we are given a set $I$ of indices and for each $i \in I$ an element $U_i \in \mathfrak P(X)$. The index set  $I$ can be *any* set. You should be aware that such an indexed collection of sets $U_i$ formally is a *function* $\phi : I \to \mathfrak P(X)$ where we write $U_i = \phi(i)$. Note that this allows $U_i = U_{i'}$ for $i \ne i'$, i.e. your indexed family of sets $U_i$ may have multiple occurences of the same set.

If we simply say that $\mathcal T \subset \mathfrak P(X)$, then we can regard $\mathcal T $ as indexed collection by taking $I = \mathcal T$ and letting $\phi : \mathcal T \to \mathfrak P(X)$ be the inclusion, i.e. $\phi(U) = U$. This may be called the "self-indexing" of $\mathcal T$.

Anyway, both approaches are correct, thus it is a matter of taste which you prefer.